# Getting a Value can not be null with ajax

Tags: jquery

I'm attempting to a pass a parameter from my view to my controller, I run into :
**Value can not be null** when I attempt to execute my action GetCompanyDataWithId.

A successful run would pass parameter to the controller which would return  JSON data used to populate my jqGrid.

---

It seems the value is not being passed properly
Any ideas?

```
$("#dropdwnlist").change(function () {
               var value = $(this).val();

               $.ajax({
                   url: '<%= Url.Action("GetCompanyDataWithId", "Billing") %>', 
                   type: "POST",                            
                   data: { companyid: "25" },
                   success: function (data) {
                       alert(data);
                       $('#Bgrid').setGridParam({ url: '<%= Url.Action("GetCompanyDataWithId", "Billing") %>'});
                       $('#Bgrid').trigger('reloadGrid');                                                    
                   },
                   error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert(xhr.responseText);
                   }

               }).done(function (msg) {
                   alert("Data Saved: " + msg);
               });
           });
```

Comment: Is'nt this really a serverside issue ?

Comment: Echoing adeneo, it looks like you have a lot more tech in this than just jQuery. I take it you're using some version of Asp.NET MVC and some table-grid plugin. It would really help people answer your question if you included those details. At the very least, you could capture the body of the Ajax request that your change function is sending and post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your controller method looks like:

```
public ActionResult GetCompanyDataWithId(string companyid) {}
```

You could use these `$.ajax` options:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ companyid: "25" }),
type: 'post',
dataType: 'json',
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
```

Or simpler:

```
Url.Action("GetCompanyDataWithId", "Billing", new { companyid = "25" })
```

Comment: `JSON.stringify` is probably not right. The controller probably expects POST data in normal `x-www-form-urlencoded` format, and jQuery will do that encoding automatically.

Comment: @Barmar, It's needed. Especially for complex objects.